# Passing parameter tu angular factory using $http

Tags: angularjs, http-post, factory

This is my factory working with angularjs

```
  app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
       return {
           getSource: function(callback) {
              var url = '...';
              $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                 callback(data);
              }
           }
       }
    }]);
```

But i want to send a parameter to this factory as :

This is my factory working with angularjs

```
  app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
       return {
           getSource: function(callback,url) {
              var url = '...';
              $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                 callback(data);
              }
           }
       }
    }]);
```

i tested with different methods but it didn't work.How can i use callbak with a parameter

Comment: What exactly did not work? To me it seems to be OK(ish).

Comment: i couldn't call with parameter url

Answer (score 0):

you seems to have problem in your code, try this:

```
  app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
       return {
           getSource: function(callback,url) {
              var url = '...';
              $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                 callback(data);
              }); // missing brace
           }
       };
    }]);
```

Comment: maybe error is coming when i call, can i sak how do you call getSource?